# Elegantly detecting the presence (and type) or absence of an Event Object inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

I have a function which I intend to fire on several different `Events`.

Importantly, the function may *also* be invoked directly.

But I need the function to **know** which event it is being fired by... or whether it is being invoked directly.

I realised I could (somehow) harness the `Event Object` and use something like:

```
const myFunction = (e) => {

  if ((e !== undefined) && (e.hasOwnProperty('type')) {

    switch (e.type) {

      case ('click'):      console.log('Click Event');       break;
      case ('mouseover'):  console.log('Mouseover Event');   break;
    }
  }

  else {

    console.log('Separately invoked');
  }
}
```

This isn't terrible, but it's more verbose than I want it to be and I'm not too keen on trying to verify the `Event Object` by checking if `e` is both *not* `undefined` *and* has a particular property... this all seems a very roundabout approach to verifying the presence of an `Event Object`.

Is there a better way to check for the [presence and type] or [absence] of an `Event Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to get the type or `"direct"` for a direct call:

```
const myFunction = (e) => {
    switch (e?.type ?? "direct") {
        case "click":
            console.log("Click Event");
            break;
        case "mouseover":
            console.log("Mouseover Event");
            break;
        case "direct":
            console.log("Separately invoked");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Other");
            break;
    }
};
```

With your inline `case` format:

```
const myFunction = (e) => {
    switch (e?.type ?? "direct") {
        case "click":     console.log("Click Event");        break;
        case "mouseover": console.log("Mouseover Event");    break;
        case "direct":    console.log("Separately invoked"); break;
        default:          console.log("Other");              break;
    }
};
```

Or without those relatively-new features, logical `&&` and `||`:

```
const myFunction = (e) => {
    switch ((e && e.type) || "direct") {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to check for the [presence and type] or [absence] of an `Event Object`?

It turns out there is.

**ES2020** introduces **Optional Chaining**, using the operator `?.` which at any point returns `undefined` if *any property* in the chain - or even the parent object - cannot be found.

This means that in any

```
const myFunction = (e) => { [... CODE HERE... ] }
```

we may use this:

```
e?.type
```

which returns:

- the `EventObject.type`, if function parameter `e` is the `Event Object`
- `undefined`, if function parameter `e` is an object / data structure lacking the property `type`
- `undefined`, if the function has been invoked without any parameter

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.myDiv');

const myFunction = (e) => {

  switch (e?.type) {

    case ('click') : console.log('Click Event'); break;
    case ('mouseover') : console.log('Mouseover Event'); break;
    default : console.log('Separately invoked');
  }
}

setInterval(myFunction, 3000);

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, false);
myDiv.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

```css
.myDiv {

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

---

### Further Reading:

- https://javascript.info/optional-chaining
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Nit: Your `default` case will be reached when the code is used for an event not in the list, not only when it's invoked directly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, sorry, that was my intention. I don't know if the UI has changed but I didn't see the box. I wondered if it had been removed. (I've used the box before so I know to look for it. If it's in the usual place and I simply didn't see it, then that's my fault.)

Comment: :-) No worries. It's at the very bottom and blends into the background well. It's in the box just above the Review your question button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0RNv.png